# How to apply gradient color text depend on the length of text?

Tags: css

I'm using the below code for gradient color texts.

```
h3 {
      background: linear-gradient( to right, #D3EDFF ,#FCAAA3 );
      -webkit-background-clip: text;
      -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
      
}
```

It's working but the gradient color effect is different in each text due to the length difference.

[image]

How do I apply the same pattern of gradient color regardless of the length of texts?

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because the background that you are setting is in the `<h3 />`, so the background `linear-gradient` its in all the element.

You must have to change the element's display to `inline-block`.

```css
h3 {
      background: linear-gradient( to right,#D3EDFF 0%, #FCAAA3 100%);
      -webkit-background-clip: text;
      -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
      display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<h3>Test</h3>
<br />
<h3>TestTestTest</h3>
```

Now the `linear-gradient` have the correct length.

You can use `width: fit-content;` instead of `display: inline-block;` and it will have the same result but without the `<br />`

```css
h3 {
      background: linear-gradient( to right,#D3EDFF 0%, #FCAAA3 100%);
      -webkit-background-clip: text;
      -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
      width: fit-content;
}
```

```html
<h3>Test</h3>
<h3>TestTestTest</h3>
```